# What is wrong with SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, savefiledialog

My program deals with image encoding, a process that is reasonable heavy, yet it is not the main `Hot Line` of the entire process. Here is what happened:

[image: SFD]

[image: Save File Dialog Hot Line]

The program just lags a lot while openning the Sfd, is this normal? It could be by the fact that i'm in a notebook (low RPM HD).

Comment: Does it happen *every* time the dialog opens, or just the first time?

Comment: It is pretty normal, particularly on a programmer's machine.  They tend to have a *lot* of shell extensions installed.  They all get loaded and initialized when you call ShowDialog().  Clean that up with SysInternals' AutoRuns utility.

Comment: @Steve First time for each run. Second time open with ~half~ of the time.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like initialization of the dialog that's taking a while, which is somewhat out of control. Listen to Hans :)